# Vue.js: EventBus being called multiple times

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-events

I'm building the logic for an 'undo delete' - action. For that, I'm using an Event Bus to send an event to two unrelated components like so:

`Undo.vue:`

```
EventBus.$emit(`confirm-delete-${this.category}`, this.item.id);
```

The name of the event(`this.category`) is based on props coming from a parent (`ConfirmDeleteModal.vue`) and then received as follows:

`CategoryA.vue`

```
created() {
   EventBus.$on('confirm-delete-category-a', (id) => {
     this.confirmDelete(id);
   });
},
```

`CategoryB.vue`

```
created() {
    EventBus.$on('confirm-delete-category-b', (id) => {
      this.confirmDelete(id);
    });
},
```

My issue: For some reason, the event for `category-a` is emitted and received **twice** (`category-b` works fine). I have to listen to the `confirm-event` constantly, therefore I can't remove the event listener after I received the event or listen only `$once`. Any ideas how to solve this (maybe with Vuex)? Thanks!

Comment: Probably because `created` runs twice? Did you debug it? Depends on how you use these components.

Comment: But CategoryA and CategoryB are different components, so `created` doesn't really run twice, does it?

Comment: Since category-a is received twice and category-b is not, there's clearly a difference between A and B somewhere. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was also facing the same kind of issue and then after some research, I got this solution.

You have defined your component `CategoryA.vue` two times in your application which is causing the function to run twice which is in this case `CategoryA.vue`

Solution:
You have to call `destroyed()` after the `created()`
Like:

```
created() {
    EventBus.$on('confirm-delete-category-a', (id) => {
      this.confirmDelete(id);
    }),
},
destroyed() {
    EventBus.$off('confirm-delete-category-a');
},
```

Comment: I have same issue. in my side i used 15 times in my page. i tried your solution but not working in my side.

Comment: can you share the relevant code so I can review.

Comment: Issue is fixed...  actually  i was doing bad practices so that that event was being occurred many times.